# Ubuntu 20.04 activities overview (super key): windows only can be selected by Down Arrow key

Tags: 20.04, activities-overview

When I press <kbd>Super</kbd>, the activities overview overlay with all current windows is displayed.
Now I would like select a certain window using arrow keys <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

But why does the windows changing only work with <kbd>↓</kbd> for the first time?  After that I will be able to use all arrow keys. Finding this behavior very unintuitive, is there a workaround for this?

For illustration I mean the following widget:

[source: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/ubuntu-17-10-gnome-shell-ambiance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQMmD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely because the focus is on the search field at the top. When you press the down arrow, you're moving the focus from the input field to the grid of applications. You can't go left or right to the grid from the input field, because the windows are below, so down arrow is correct.

This is (I believe) the default behaviour in GNOME, so if you desire a change to this, I think you'd need to file a bug upstream against GNOME Shell.

Comment: This is surprising behavior. Right/left arrows keys in the search field make sense, if there is already something typed - otherwise they probably would be better suited to directly change the windows. It is a bit puzzling in current form, as there no visual focus indicator on the empty search. When I have a bit more time, I'll suggest a feature/bug request. Thanks for the help!